# Woocommerce Show Message on Cart Page Based on Product Category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a Woocommerce store.  After items are added to the cart, I am trying to insert in a different piece of text beneath the product image on the cart page based on the category that product belongs to.

For Example:
Product 1 from Category Shirts 
Display Message 1

Product 2 from Category Shoes 
Display Message 2

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be anything that you can hook into after the product thumbnail so my advice would be to copy the template `\woocommerce\templates\cart\cart.php` into your theme folder and modify it to display the text under the product thumbnail inside the table cell with class `product-thumbnail`

Here's a start to get the product categories you can try and finish it yourself ;)

```
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
$cat_ids = $product->get_category_ids();
```

This will return an array of ids that you can use the function `get_the_category()` to loop over and get the category names.

Comment: I have locate the spot in the cart.php file I need to add the code. The issues I'm having is, how to determine what category the product is from and how to display a different message based on that info.

Comment: I've added some extra code above to get you started.